# Android QR reader with Zxing

Tags: java, android, zxing

When I read Qr code, `textView` doesn't change.(Question 1) What is the problem ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{


private Button buton;
private TextView textView;
private ZXingScannerView myview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myview = new ZXingScannerView(MainActivity.this);

            myview.setResultHandler(MainActivity.this);
            setContentView(myview);
            myview.startCamera();


        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myview.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView.setText(result.getText().toString());
    myview.stopCamera();


}
}
```

And when I finished reading Qr code,I want to start new activty with `result`. 
(Question 2) How I do it ? Will this code work ?

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    myview.stopCamera();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivty.class);
    intent.putExtra("Result",result);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

If it doesn't, how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` from `handleResult`. You're replacing the view that you have references to with a new view.

As for communicating the `Result` over intent, as is, what you have will not work. `Result` does not inherit from `Parcelable`, and you can't just stick it in an intent and expect it to work. Better would be to get all relevant info from the `Result` and put it in the `Intent` as a String.

Comment: It doesn't work, when read qr code, camere doesn't stop, don't show activty interface

Comment: Do this then: save the view you set as the content view with `(*whatever the top level view is in activity_main.xml*) mainView = (*whatever the top level view is in activity_main.xml*) findViewById(android.R.id.content);` after calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`, and then in `handleResult()`, `setContentView(mainView);`